# Can we predict a person's tolerance to cold exposure during excercise?

Tags: human-biology, literature, fitness

Being an amateur athlete and student of anatomy I've always wanted to know if there is a formula for determining an unconditioned body's tolerance to cold temperatures while exercising.

I know the factors of age,weight, gender, humid versus dry weather etc. are going to make it tough to determine.

Has there been any research into formulaicly describing a persons cold temperature tolerance?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bio.SE! The original question invited homebrew formulas which *could* be opinion based. I've made an edit that asks for a more established method. Feel free to role back on the edit!

Comment: The first thing I'd look for is some kind of acclimatization index.  Even if all the other factors mentioned are the same, people living at different heights or different biomes (desert v tundra) will have different cold temp tolerance.